# Crop the border of an image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I crop the border of an image using PIL?

From an image like this
[image: Start]

I want make to this
[image: Result]

Comment: You probably need to look up "image cropping" for PIL, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9983361/532471

Comment: on what basis do you intend to crop the image???

Comment: Geekfish, no  i doesn t know where pointed digits borders. I want cut only digits from the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img = Image.open('your_wonderful_image.png')
nonwhite_positions = [(x,y) for x in range(img.size[0]) for y in range(img.size[1]) if img.getdata()[x+y*img.size[0]] != (255,255,255)]
rect = (min([x for x,y in nonwhite_positions]), min([y for x,y in nonwhite_positions]), max([x for x,y in nonwhite_positions]), max([y for x,y in nonwhite_positions]))
img.crop(rect).save('out.png')
```