# how to crop and rotate a part of image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to extract a object of interest (a vehicle ) from a large picture, now I know the 4 coordinates of this vehicle in the picture. How could I crop the image of this vehicle in the picture and then rotate it to 90 degree as shown below

[image]

I need to program it in python, but I don’t know which library to use for this functionality ?

Comment: use PIL. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL
there is also a good tutorial for simple tasks - http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

cropping - http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm#cutting-pasting-and-merging-images

rotating - http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm#geometrical-transforms

Comment: In addition to the already proposed PIL, I would add [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [scikits-image](http://scikit-image.org/). Although any of those libraries are a bit an overkill solution for just rotating an object, they might be useful if in the future you need to do something slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("img.jpg")
im.rotate(45)
```

You also have a crop method ...

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use PIL and do it like here : 
   [Crop the image using PIL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983263/crop-the-image-using-pil-in-python)
2. You could use OpenCV and do it like here:
   [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

For the rotation you could use OpenCV's cv::transpose().

Rotating using PIL: http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0201/