# How to crop an image from the center with certain dimensions?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, crop

Say we have an image with the following dimensions:

```
width = 200
height = 100
```

Say that the dimensions of our crop would be `50x50`.

How can I crop an image using this new dimension from the **center** of the image, using Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983263/crop-the-image-using-pil-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume a crop box with the dimensions: `cw, ch = 50, 50`.

The center of the image is the point `(w//2, h//2)`, where `w` is its width and `h` is its height. The square crop box which is 50 pixels on a side would also be centered there.

This means the upper left corner of the crop box would be at `(w//2 - cw//2, h//2 - ch//2)`, and its lower right corner is at `(w//2 + cw//2, h//2 + ch//2)`.

There's at least *two* ways to crop the image I can think of. The first is to use the [`Image.crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) method and pass it the coordinates of the rectangular crop region.

```
box = w//2 - cw//2, h//2 - ch//2, w//2 + cw//2, h//2 + ch//2
cropped_img = img.crop(box)
```

Which can be simplified mathematically to cut down on the number of divisions:

```
box = (w-cw)//2, (h-ch)//2, (w+cw)//2, (h+ch)//2  # left, upper, right, lower
cropped_img = img.crop(box)
```

Another way to do it is via the [`ImageOps.crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/PIL/ImageOps.html#crop) function which is passed the size of the border on each of the four sides:

```
from PIL import ImageOps

wdif, hdif = (w-cw)//2, (h-ch)//2
border = wdif, hdif, wdif, hdif  # left, top, right, bottom
cropped_img = ImageOps.crop(img, border)
```

Comment: Great answer! Just a quick question. Why should we divide 50 by 2 (50//2)? Thanks.

Comment: @Simplicity: It's `50//2` because that half of the 50 pixel width and height of the crop box. It's ½ because the box is centered, so that much of it lies on either side of that midpoint.