# How to take only the part i want to take a screenshot? (windows, python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshot

This code takes a screenshot of the entire program.
I want to take screenshots of only a small part of the program.

Even if i change w(wide) and h(height) in the code below
screenshot is taken starting from the top left corner of the program.

For example, this code can range from 0,0 (top left) to the desired x,y.
But what I want is to take a screenshot from x1,y1 to x2,y2. What do I need to add or modify?

(I used google translator. I've tried to explain it as best as I can.)
thank you

```
from tkinter import *
import win32gui
import win32ui
from PIL import Image
from ctypes import windll

def screenshot():

    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'program_name') #input program name
    
    #left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd) 
    w = right - left #wide
    h = bot - top #hight

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

    #result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 1)

    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGB',
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
        bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

    if result == 1: #if Succeeded
        im.save("C:/Users/Moon/Desktop/test.png") #save path need change
    
    else:
        print("Error")


screenshot()
```

Comment: You could create another bitmap and `BitBlt` into that. Or, probably easier to just crop the pil image. [How to crop an image using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9983361)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).